# react-native-router-flux tabbar styling on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, tabbar, react-native-router-flux

Seems like RNRF is using safeAreaView or something to add extra padding below the rendered tabbar:

[image]

Which is good and all because it makes sure my tab bar clicking experience wouldn't be interfered with the bottom bit of iPhone X screen as you can see in the image.

But I just need to access that padding to modify it to my liking. i.e. the height of the padding and if I want to disable the padding altogether and just expand the buttons themselves to the bottom of the screen.

So far I can only modify its color by adding `backgroundColor` to `tabBarStyle` props on the `Scene` component.

Been reading the docs to see if there's any specific mention of styling for iPhone X but no luck.

Is there anything I can do to modify the padding level?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: So, I've given up trying to work around it and just supplied the scene with a custom tabBar instead, which takes considerably less time than trying to work around it lol

Answer (score 0):

I know that it might be too late for you, but hope I can help others that finds this post as late as I did. Setting `safeAreaInset={{bottom: 'never'}}>` in the `Tabs` component made the SafeAreaView allow the `Scene` components to reach the bottom of the screen.

As react-native-router-flux is based on React Navigation, I searched that API and found `safeAreaInset` [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator)